# Compiling a package-structured Java program with jars from terminal

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal

I need to be able to compile and run a Java project from the terminal, and without using something like Maven or Gradle. The project structure looks something like this:

```
    project
        src
          package1
             Main.java
          package2
             Class1.java
             Class2.java
        bin
        lib
          jar1.jar
          jar2.jar
```

`Main.java` contains the `main()` method, and it needs `Class1` and `Class2` in order to run. It also needs the `.jar` files `jar1` and `jar2`, located in the lib folder. I would like all of the .class files to be in the bin folder.

I've tried my hand at figuring out the terminal command in order to compile and run the program but am a bit stuck. This is the best I've managed to figure out:

```
    cd project
    javac -d bin/ -cp lib/jar1.jar:lib/jar2.jar src/package2/*.java src/package1/*.java
```

This successfully compiles, but then when I try to run `Main.java`:

```
    java -cp lib/jar1.jar:lib/jar2.jar src/package1/Main
```

I get the following error:

```
    error: invalid flag: src/package1/Main
    Usage: javac <options> <source files>
    use --help for a list of possible options
```

Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to give the class name like `package1.Main`.  And add your `bin` to the `-cp` flag. But why does it say `javac` in what you say is an error from `java` (not `javac`)?

Comment: @Thilo I realise that I had included the incorrect error message in my post. But besides that, your solution helped me get it working! Thanks so much.